# Unable to send google mail CodeIgniter with ubuntu server

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, smtp, gmail

**Im try to send email using gmail with codeIgniter. here is my code :**

function sendemail($name,$key, $email) {

```
    $this -> load -> library('email');      

    $econfig['protocol'] = "smtp";
    $econfig['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.googlemail.com";
    $econfig['smtp_port'] = 465;
    $econfig['smtp_user'] = "*******@gmail.com"; 
    $econfig['smtp_pass'] = "******";
    $econfig['charset'] = "utf-8";
    $econfig['mailtype'] = "html";

    $this -> email -> initialize($econfig);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this -> email -> from('*********@gmail.com', 'Asoft Administration');
    $this -> email -> to($email);

    $this -> email -> subject('Subject');
    $this -> email -> message("HTML MESSAGE");

    if (!$this -> email -> send()) {
        echo $this -> email -> print_debugger();
        return false;
    } else {            
        return true;
    }
}
```

**My Environment is ubuntu server. Im never use postfix or sendmail. Is it required to send gmail mails ?. i double checked user name and password.!**

**After try send email im get this error.**

hello: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [2607:5300:100:200::377]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 CHUNKING

Failed to authenticate password. Error: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14

from: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1

The following SMTP error was encountered: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1  - gsmtp 
to: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1

The following SMTP error was encountered: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 
data: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1

The following SMTP error was encountered: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 
502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command. j4sm48430630qaf.31 - gsmtp 
The following SMTP error was encountered: 502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command. j4sm48430630qaf.31 - gsmtp 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

User-Agent: CodeIgniter

Date: Thu, 3 Jul 2014 11:20:14 +0200

From: "Asoft Administration" <******@gmail.com>

Return-Path: <******@gmail.com>

To: ******@gmail.com

Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Qsi_Member_confirmation_mail?=

Reply-To: "******@gmail.com" <******.com>

X-Sender: ******@gmail.com

X-Mailer: CodeIgniter

X-Priority: 3 (Normal)

Message-ID: <53b5204ed3324@gmail.com>

Mime-Version: 1.0

Anyone can help me ... Thanks lot.

Comment: Try loading the email library below the config settings, like so: `$this->load->library('email', $econfig);` (not using `initialise`)

Comment: I tried your instruction and then it was give this error..

"Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method."

Comment: It's not two factor authentication or anything like that is it?

Comment: Have you logged in on the corresponding gmail account? Sometimes it will complain about "suspicious" activity when you first try using its SMTP. If you then discard it as "non suspicious", gmail will allow future mails being sent through its service.

Comment: Yeah Mudshark its the problem. thanks a lot. I logged in server corresponding mail after no problem at all work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem, here is my working code:

```
$config = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'my@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE
);

$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from('my@gmail.com', 'Niraj');
$this->email->to($email);
$this->email->subject('SOME SUBJECT');
$this->email->message('<p>Some Content</p>');
$this->email->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Google want to authorize when it trying to send first time. Google send message to corresponding email whether you want to enable use this email via unsecured app.